# SPO Calculate the difference between two dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, list-form, formula

I am trying to create a calculated column which shows the number of days' difference between two columns which have dates in them. I understand that I can get this with the following formula:

```
=DATEDIF([Column 1],[Column 2],"D")
```

But when i trigger the calculated column in a flow and show the days calculated in an email it look likes for example:
[image]

So what i should use in the formula to remove all the zeros ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What are your settings on the calculated field? Is it returning a number? And if so with how many decimals?

Comment: Yes in my list it's returning number without zeros, in the email it shows the zeros no idea why.Take a look here in my list: https://i.imgur.com/v4lslQd.png @JohanBrännmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula.

```
int(triggerBody()?['DateDif'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251383/working-with-column-formatting-using-json-rounding-decimal-values) might help. The accepted answer says to just put your current column formula inside ROUND:

```
=ROUND([your formula here],0)
```